# Get all nodes with relationships

Tags: neo4j

[image: Tree structure]

I want a query in which if I send Name: "Johnson" it should all nodes that are directly and indirectly connected in a data format shown in the image.  How would I query to get all connected nodes in data format with the relationship between the primary node and the related node?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [variable-length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) pattern.

For example, to get the desired paths from a person named 'Johnson' (which I presume is unique) to each relative:

```
MATCH path = (p:Person)-[:Father|Mother|Son|daughter|Wife *]-(:Person)
WHERE p.name = 'Johnson'
RETURN path
```